# How to import winscp.ini to a new computer

Tags: import, configuration-files, winscp

My hard drive crashed, but I have WinSCP configuration saved to `winscp.ini`

So I bought a new hard drive and formatted my PC and installed a WinSCP on my computer

Now I want to import the `.ini` file so that I have my saved sessions.

Answer (score 4):

On [WinSCP Login dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login), go to the *Tools > Import/Restore configuration*, navigate to your external harddisk and select the exported INI file.

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/config#import

---

*Note that if you do not know how to browse external harddisk, you should ask a specific question on that. Preferably on https://superuser.com/*.

Answer (score 0):

Sesssion-->Sites-->Site Manager --> Tools-->Import/Restore OR Export/Backup

Version 5.21.2